# How to get the cordinates of an Item in Game view in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a slider in Unity, and I'm having a problem with getting the Cordinates of the Gameview or whatever this Window is:
[image: Image of Unity Scene]

to set the location of the light Bar in between the two moovable dots. When I try Using Transform.position it gives me its global position. I hope someone understands what I am asking,
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The area you are pointing at is Canvas. By default it's location is (0;0;0) therefore meaning all elements' local positions to Canvas are same as global.

To get control's local position you may use transform.localPosition(). Link with example:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html